# Querying JSON column with nested arrays

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Below is my JSON and query I've built so far, I feel like I'm just missing some silly piece. These data files are loaded as-is into SQL Server tables, so this JSON exists in one column.

Ultimately the nested array comes back null and it's subsequent fields come back null.

**Would like to see how to alter my query to  pull the "plans" as its array and alternatively how to pull the individual fields from it**

JSON Example

```
{"carrierPlans": [{"carrierId": 90, "carrierName": "Community Care", "plans": [{"planId": 170, "planName": "Silver", "pbpId": "H167"}]}]}
```

Query

```
-- carrierplans
SELECT  
c.[carrierId],
c.[carrierName],
c.[pbpId],
c.[planName],
c.[planId]
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[LoadTable] b
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (b.[array]) -- array is the json column
WITH (
[carrierId] varchar(50),
[carrierName] varchar(50),
[pbpId] varchar(50),
[planName] varchar(50),
[planId] varchar(50)
) c
WHERE [key] = 'carrierplans'
```

OR if I wanted to capture the plans array something like this

```
SELECT  
c.[carrierId],
c.[carrierName],
c.[plans]
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[LoadTable] b
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (b.[array]) -- array is the json column
WITH (
[carrierId] varchar(50),
[carrierName] varchar(50),
[plans] varchar(50)
) c
WHERE [key] = 'carrierplans'
```

Current Result

```
carrierId   carrierName pbpId   planName    planId
90          Community Care  NULL    NULL            NULL
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, j NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (j) VALUES
(N'{
    "carrierPlans": [
        {
            "carrierId": 90,
            "carrierName": "Community Care",
            "plans": [
                {
                    "planId": 170,
                    "planName": "Silver",
                    "pbpId": "H167"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1
SELECT carrierId = JSON_VALUE(a.Value,'$.carrierId')
    , carrierName = JSON_VALUE(a.Value,'$.carrierName')
    , c.*
FROM @tbl AS t
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (j, '$.carrierPlans') AS a
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (A.value, '$.plans') 
WITH (
    [planId] INT'$.planId',
    [carrierName] varchar(50) '$.planName',
    [pbpId] varchar(50) '$.pbpId'
) as c;

-- Method #2
SELECT carrierId = JSON_VALUE(a.Value,'$.carrierId')
    , carrierName = JSON_VALUE(a.Value,'$.carrierName')
    , plans = b.value
FROM @tbl AS t
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (j, '$.carrierPlans') AS a
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (A.Value, '$.plans') AS b;

-- Method #3
SELECT carrierId = JSON_VALUE(a.Value,'$.carrierId')
    , carrierName = JSON_VALUE(a.Value,'$.carrierName')
    , plans = JSON_QUERY(a.Value,'$.plans')
FROM @tbl AS t
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (j, '$.carrierPlans') AS a;
```

**Output #1**

| carrierId | carrierName | planId | carrierName | pbpId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | Community Care | 170 | Silver | H167 |

Output #2

| carrierId | carrierName | plans |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | Community Care | {"planId": 170,"planName": "Silver","pbpId": "H167"} |

Comment: This works for pulling all fields out. Is it possible have those first two columns for "carrierId" and "carrierName" and apply/join the "plans" array column in it's json array format??

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, ##1-4

Comment: I added Method #2 to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Also, I  added Method #3.

Answer (score 0):

I found this impossible to do, the JSON support in SQL server is good, but limited.

I changed to using XML instead, they have selective queries that are very fully featured and this let me query inside nested blocks, and index on parts of the xml document.

you end up with queries like this:

```
SELECT xnodes.vals.value('.', 'int') AS [Carrier] FROM [LoadTable]
  CROSS APPLY MyXMLColumn.nodes('/carrierPlans') AS xnodes(vals) 
WHERE xnodes.vals.value('./@carrierID', 'int') = '90'
```

[this link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/getting-started-with-xml-indexes/) was very useful for the concepts, and [this one](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/precision-indexing-basics-of-selective-xml-indexes-in-sql-server-2012/) for creating indexes - selective indexing is where the power is, and its really good.

The disadvantage is you have to create XML documents instead of JSON, and maybe MS will add the same kind of selective indexing power to JSON queries as we have in XML.

Comment: *"the JSON support in SQL server is good, but limited."* I concur. It is comparable with the SQL Server 2000 XML API.